# What's with the "cockatoo jump scare" in Citizen Kane?

Tags: citizen-kane

[image]

[Youtube link to just before this "jump scare" happens](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lz44Jzj45iE&t=0m25s)

According to the internet, this painfully loud screech was Welles' attempt to wake up the viewer. For me it was a complete immersion breaker in an otherwise great film, and the "waking people up" explanation simply doesn't make any sense to me.

I understand that the missing eye is a technical error (like the infamous pterodactyls in another scene), but why did anyone think this particular scene needed to start with something loud and sudden enough to give people a heart attack?

Comment: _"According to the internet"_ ... do you mean [Orson Welles himself](https://youtu.be/aHI5BYmWDtU?t=362)?

Comment: @Oliver_C "The internet" seemed to be citing some DVD commentary thing I don't have access too; that particular youtube clip sounds like Welles making a joke.

Answer (score 7):

Amazingly, ***the internet is right about this one.*** ;)

There *are* some other theories floating around about the symbolism behind this (a prevalent one is that this screeching pet bird flying away is superimposed over Susan, a bad opera singer, when she 'flies the coop' because that's how the shocked and bitter Kane imagines the situation). But Welles *really has* maintained that the cockatoo is there just to wake the audience up.

You see him briefly saying it in [the clip that Oliver has provided](https://youtu.be/aHI5BYmWDtU?t=362) in his comment - but even if you think it was just a throwaway joke there, you should know that Welles repeated this explanation *several* times. One of them was in an interview with director Peter Bogdanovich (available in [Orson Welles's Citizen Kane: A Casebook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/019515892X)), where Bogdanovich asks him about it *repeatedly* and Welles insists that there's no other
meaning behind it, and I see no reason to believe he was joking there or lying to Bogdanovich. Here's the relevant segment:

> PB: Why did you use that shrieking cockatoo?
>
> OW: Wake 'em up.
>
> PB: Literally?
>
> OW: Yeah. Getting late in the evening, you know - time to brighten up anybody who might be nodding off. [laughs]
>
> PB: It has no other purpose?
>
> OW: **Theatrical shock effect, if you want to be grand about it** - you can say it's placed at a certain musical moment when I felt the need for something short and exclamatory. **So it has a sort of purpose, but no *meaning*.**

*[And yes, Welles also confirms later in the interview that the see-through eye was just a glitch.]*

Comment: Are you fully back \o/

Comment: @AnkitSharma Just barely... :/